# Smooth screen recording software

Tags: windows

I am preparing for my senior thesis presentation. I'd like to back myself up in case there is no internet connection available. Therefore I want to record a video showing the functionality of my software. I have tried Camtasia but all the smooth and slick animations I've created, do not look that appealing. Is there an alternative. Something that will capture my screen 1 to 1, or near that. Camtasia is great, but it does not serve the purpose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Kiril

Answer (score 3):

List of [screencasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screencasting_software) software

Also, this [ScreenToaster](http://www.screentoaster.com/) [demo](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2009/01/screentoaster_records_screencasts_and_audio_no_software_required-2/) looks pretty smooth, and it just came out this year.  Another [demo](http://www.screentoaster.com/watch/demo/screentoaster). Thats pretty slick.  You can download the video later as a .mov file.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [webex](http://www.webex.com/) for such screen recording work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned Microsoft's Expression Encoder screen capture software.  It has probably the best quality I've ever seen from a screen recording software, and is super easy to use.  You can also capture a webcam and/or audio output/input.  Check it out - http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Encoder4_Overview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using the "Capture Movie" feature in VMWare Workstation. Being able to reset your environment back to a specific point for a retake may make it easier to record a perfect shot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, screen recording software work as a "parasite" on your operating system, they don't necessarily get "switched in" every time the frame buffer changes or something in your video card changes.

I'm therefore not sure that you can find something that records 1:1. You might be able to improve things with increased process priority, no compression, etc., but I still doubt you'd capture every frame.

Answer (score 0):

For making software demos, [**DemoCreator**](http://www.sameshow.com/demo-creator.html#107) would be a nice tool. It will capture your screen 1 to 1 if you don't mean to resize the dimension of the Flash movie. And it is with powerful editing features for you to add callouts to make the dome easier to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

im using a pretty screen record tool - PCHand Screen Recorder. 
it could record anything on the screen. and i think it is the perfect assistant to create instructional video for u. what's more, it could record any audio and keep synchronous with video.
hope it could help u.

http://www.screen-capture-record.com/screen-recorder.html

Answer (score 0):

I like the Blueberry Software offering. I have used it and not noticed any flickering.

They can be found here: http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [WM Capture](http://wmrecorder.com/products/wm-capture/). They have a free download which lets you record up to 10 minutes. The resulting file is very good quality, plus you can adjust the audio/video bitrate and frames per second.

To compress the resulting file to something more manageable, I use VLC media player, which has some excellent (but little known) built-in conversion features (via the Media -> Convert/Save menu option). This resulted in the 30mb mpg file from WM capture to be a 3mb mpg file without any noticable degredation of quality.